# How to aggregate in cross-tab style items in a linked model to its parent?

Tags: python, django

I wish to construct a cross-tab view from the model structure shown below.
I want a matrix with Calendar dates down the LHS, Course names across the top, and something in each cell denoting presence of a Booking instance on that date/course.

Simplified model structure:

```
class Calendar(models.Model):
    crCalDate = models.DateField(primary_key=True)

class Course(models.Model):
    ceName = models.CharField()

class CourseBooking(models.Model):
    cbCourse = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='booked_course')
    cbDay = models.ForeignKey(Calendar, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='booked_day')
```

My view function's queryset at present:

```
class DayView(ListView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        # construct index of course tuples
        course_index = [(cn['id'], 'course' + str(i)) for i, cn in enumerate(Course.objects.order_by('id').values('id'))]
        coursebookings = CourseBooking.objects.filter(cbDay__crCalDate__gte=dt.datetime.today()).values('id', 'cbDay__crCalDate', 'cbCourse__id', 'cbCourse__ceName')
        calendar_dates = list(Calendar.objects.filter(crCalDate__gte=dt.datetime.today()).order_by('crCalDate').values('crCalDate', 'crSunrise', 'crSunset'))
        for cb in coursebookings:
            for i, cal in enumerate(calendar_dates):
                if cal['crCalDate'] == cb['cbDay__crCalDate']:
                    course = [ci[1] for ci in course_index if ci[0] == cb['cbCourse__id']]
                    if course:
                        calendar_dates[i][course[0]] = 'Occupied'
                    break
        return calendar_dates
```

This all feels rather tedious and expensive, and I wonder am I going about this the wrong way, having unsuccessfully tried `annotate()` and `aggregate()` functions to achieve a suitable summary query.

As a bonus, I really want to be able to show the number of booking lines for each Course on each Calendar day, rather than the text I presently insert there.
The additional model representing this is as follows:

```
class BookLine(models.Model):
    blTime = models.TimeField(verbose_name='Booking Time')
    blDay = models.ForeignKey(CourseBooking, on_delete = models.CASCADE, db_index=True, related_name='bookinglines')
```

Any guidance on a better means to achieve this is much appreciated, or even to validate this methodology (aside from my bonus requirement above).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look too bad. You have three database queries on the outside of your for loops, so it's not an N+1 query problem. I can't say I could understand what followed at a casual glance.

You could use just a single query to get hold of a list of `CourseBooking` objects or values annotated with `ceName` and `crCalDate` values. You can also filter by those values. You could then run just a single pass through all those objects or values, setting up a dict-of-dicts `calendar_dates[date][course]`.

You'd then have to obtain a set of courses present in any of the course-dicts, and convert that into a list to use as the top headers. Then work through the dates, replacing each courses-dict with a courses-list with an appropriate table element value.

I think this code would probably be clearer, but if the code you have is working, it may not be worth your time changing it. However, it would let you count, most simply by making the inner course-dicts into collections.Counter objects. Note that Counters have a default value of 0 for any key, you never get KeyError.

```
table = {}
for obj in course_bookings:  # annotated with date_anno and course_anno
    date, course = obj.date_anno, obj.course_anno
    if date not in table:
         table[date] = Counter() # or make table a DefaultDict
    table[date][course] += 1

course_headers = set()
for course_dict in table:
   course_headers.update( course_dict.keys() )

course_headers = sorted( list( course_headers))
date_column = sorted( table.keys() )
```

You would then build a list-of-lists by iterating over `date_column` and `course_headers` pulling out the counts in the right order before passing them to be rendered. Or, you could use a trick I recently discovered:

```
class DotDict( dict):
    def __getattr__( self, key):
        return self[attr] # or with a default None, self.get( attr, None)
```

which is a dict in all respects other than you can't usefully use `setattr` on it because `getattr` has been made the same as indexing it ... so the Django template engine can refer to `{{dotdict.key}}`  without needing fancy custom template tags. Works equally well inheriting from Counter.

Comment: @ nigel: one of the things confusing me is the annotate function. It always wants an aggregation like Sum, Count, but here I simply want to 'group_by' `ceName` and `crCalDate` values (and then do my Counting on the `BookLine` model?

Comment: Thinking more, in this case using my approach, you don't need annotate at all, just `select_related()` so the queryset pre-fetches the related objects, or a values list: `CourseBooking.objects.all().values_list('cbCourse__ceName','cbDay__crCalDate')` to fetch only the data you need (which is more efficient if the objects have lots of irrelevant fields you didn't show in the question).